# Php error sending mail locally with smtp server

Tags: php, email, smtp, wamp

I'm learning how to send mail with php, so I'm testing it locally in XAMPP. I'm using Mercury for my mail server, and I used [this guide](http://system66.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-send-mail-from-localhost-with.html) to set it up, but when I try to send a mail I get this error message:

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "grid2i-ent.seg.att.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in E:\xampp\htdocs\userSystem\etest.php on line 7
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: root@localhost.com' . "\r\n";

mail("root@localhost.com", "Subject", "Hello", $headers);//This is line 7
```

And here is my php.ini mail settings:

```
SMTP = grid2i-ent.seg.att.com
smtp_port = 25
```

Comment: Likely a problem with your SMTP server -- you could always try a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would bet that it is your firewall -- but here are my suggestions

1). Take the "Headers" out - you don't really need those - at least not if you're sending a test message to yourself that doesn't actually have HTML content in it.

2). Use a different SMTP server - perhaps one provided by your personal Gmail account.

3). root@localhost.com will not work if your SMTP server is not the same place as 'localhost'

Answer (score -1):

Try using an e-mail library like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: No library will work if it is a problem with the SMTP server.

Comment: The mail() function in PHP will not work only with the SMTP server  correctly configured in the php.ini. You need to correctly configure the mail server too. With PHPMailer you don't need to bother with any configurations on the server at all. Just provide the SMTP address and port to PHPMailer.

Comment: If the smtp server is not configured correctly, it doesn't matter what you use --- Also, I remember being able to use mail() without any configuration, whatsoever - and that the perk about using these libraries (i personally use SwiftMailer) -- was to keep things outta spam -- but then again, I run Linux on everything, so it is probably configured automatically.